# C++ - std::map Alternative that doesn't require casting

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I am using an std::map to store certain objects. The map has the template `<Coordinate, Object>`. Now, what I noticed is that the map casts the Coordinate to an integer, and then based on that gives the element a unique key. (Equal to that integer)

Now, the problem is that it's impossible to convert a 3 dimensional integer (x, y, z) to a single integer, that the std::map can use.

What alternatives are there to std::map which do require the key object to be unique, but don't require it to be casted to an integer (or string etc.)?

Comment: *"what I noticed is that the map casts the Coordinate to an integer"* -- You lost me.  I have no idea what you're talking about.  Could you possibly present some code to help demonstrate your problem?

Comment: To check in what order the Map should put the values, it does key1 < key2. Obviously this isn't possible with the Coordinate struct. My initial conclusion was that I needed a way to convert the coordinate to a single integer, but I don't. I can just implement a < operator for it to use as @juanchopanza suggested.

Comment: A 3 dimensional integer can easily be converted to a single integer, and vice versa, if you're willing to triple the integral width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Coordinate` as a key to the map. You just have to define a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) for it (something akin to a less-than or greater-than comparison). How you do that is up to you, but you could, for instance, perform a lexicographical comparison using the 3 coordinates:

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

struct Coordinate
{
  double x, y, z;
  ....

  bool operator<(const Coordinate& rhs) const
  {
    return std::tie(x, y, z) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.z);
  }
};
```

Here, this is done by in the implementation of a les-than operator for `Coordinate`, but you can also define a functor and use it to construct the map:

```
struct Comp
{
  bool operator()(const Coordinate& lhs, const Coordinate& rhs) const
  {
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y, lhs.z) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.z);
  }
};
```

then

```
std::map<Coordinate, ValueType, Comp> m;
```

Comment: ooo I didn't even though about adding a compare operator